# Try and catch around unwrapping line? Swift 2.0, XCode 7

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, swift2, xcode7

I have the following unwrapping line in my code:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL((NSURL(string: url)!))`

Sometimes there occurs this fatal error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know why this error sometimes occurs, but is there a way to make a **try - catch statement around this line**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not what try and catch are for. `!` means "if this is nil, then crash." If you don't mean that, then don't use `!` (hint: you very seldom want to use `!`). Use `if-let` or `guard-let`:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

If you already have a `try` block and want to turn this situation into a `throw`, that's what `guard-let` is ideal for:

```
guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else { throw ...your-error... }
// For the rest of this scope, you can use url normally
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Comment: Is `throw` a keyword in the `guard let`?

Comment: Cheers. I'm learning that error is a type. And a term. Not a casual word describing my default behaviour.